# Why is air considered to rise adiabatically?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, air, adiabatic, meteorology

Do air parcels not push against other air and do work on them? When air molecules within an air parcel bump into air molecules outside the air parcel do they not transfer energy to them?

Answer (score 3):

When a parcel of warm air rises it expands, and so cools by doing work on the surrounding air.  The process is usually taken to be adiabatic (isentropic) because there is not much  time for heat to be conducted into or out of the parcel from/to the surrounding air.

Comment: Not much time for heat to be conducted?  We are talking about vertical adiabatic temperature variations on the order of kilometers, and the vertical velocities are certainly not on the order of km/sec.  There is plenty of time for heat conduction to occur between adjacent parcels.  But the temperature variations between adjacent air parcels are very low.

Answer (score 3):

On the spatial scale of variations in the atmosphere, the adjacent parcels are experiencing almost the exact same expansions and compressions as the parcel being considered, so there are essentially no significant spatial temperature differences to drive exchange of heat.

Comment: But in cases of convective flow where there is warm air rising up one column, and then cold air descending in another column, there is significant temperature differences. Or for instance if you have a patch of bare land next to a forest, there are significant temperature differences, and you get thermals rising from the bare land.

Comment: That is still on a larger spatial scale than I was referring to.  The surface to volume ratio is too low on that scale for a great amount of heat transfer to occur.